# Comparison of two categories over a specific period of time

Tags: technical-writing, grammar

Year:       2009 / 2019

Mobile use: 15% / 26%

Table use:  5% / 19%

what is the correct way to describe changes in two different years? I have tried to describe the changes in three different sentences, yet I am not sure if the grammar is correct, especially the use of present perfect.

1. The percentage of mobile phone users has increased by almost three-quarters from 15% to 26%, **and the percentage of tablet users is seeing an almost four-fold increase from 5% to 19%**.
2. The percentage of mobile phone users has increased by almost three-quarters from 15% to 26%, **and the percentage of tablet users has increased by almost four-fold from 5% to 19%.**
3. The percentage of mobile phone users and tables users **which accounted for one-fifth in 2009** (15% and 5%, respectively), has more than doubled to 45% in 2019 (26% and 19%, respectively).
4. The percentage of mobile phone users and tablet users accounted for one-fifth in 2009 (15% and 5% respectively), and has more than doubled to 45% in 2019 (26% and 19%, respectively).

[image]

Comment: It's not the use that has increased, it's the percentages that have changed. If mobile use increased from 15% to 26% of all users, but the number of users fell from 1000 to 100, then the number of mobile users would decline from 150 to 26. You're best just to say "the percentage of users on mobile increased from 15% to 26%".

Comment: @StuartF I have edited the phrase. is there any other comment on the sentences.

Comment: It's not really a *writing* question as such, more of an English language usage one. Also, your four examples have very different meaning so choosing the "right" one between them is kind of fruitless.